# Number of conjugacy classes or bounds for the index of stabilizers on finite Coxeter groups.

Tags: finite-groups, coxeter-groups

For a finite group $G$ denote by $\operatorname{conj}\left(G\right)$ the number of conjugacy classes of $G$ and let $q\left(G\right)$ be the quotient:

\begin{align}
q\left(G\right)=\frac{\operatorname{conj}\left(G\right)}{|G|}
\end{align}

It's obvious that $0<q\left(G\right) \le 1$ and it's $1$ iff $G$ is abelian. Obviously the number $q\left(G\right)$ is **"small"** when $\operatorname{conj}\left(G\right)$ is small with respect to $|G|$.

**Informally**: The number $q\left(G\right)$ is small when the conjugacy classes are big **for a lot of** $g\in G$. This is equivalent to say that the stabilizer $C_G\left(g\right)$ is small (has a big index) for a lot of $g\in G$. In particular the center $Z\left(G\right)$ has small index.

I'm looking for families of examples of non abelian finite Coxeter groups having small $q\left(G\right)$. Intuitively I think that for Coxeter groups this numbers in general is **"small"**.  (for me: the smaller the better).

One example: Let $G= S_n$ the symmetric group then $q \left(S_n \right)= p\left(n \right) / n!$ where $p\left(n \right)$ denotes the partitions of $n$. Note that $q\left(S_n \right)\to 0$.

By small I don't require some condition like the above $q\left(S_n \right)\to 0$ it's up to you what it means by small and I'll see if it's useful. For example If you know that $G_i$ is a family of Coxeter groups with $q\left(Q_i \right)< 1/3$ that's good and if other family has an upper bound of $1/10$ that's even good.

If someone knows some results about the number of conjugacy classes for Coxeter groups or at least some boundaries for the index of the stabilizers I would really appreciate it.

Comment: The dihedral groups of order $4n$ has $q(G) = \frac{n+3}{4n}$ and the ones of order $4n+2$ have $q(G) = \frac{n+2}{4n+2}$. So these are at least close to $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: You can probably calculate the numbers for the other types in GAP (though as far as I recall, the packages for Coxeter groups have not been updated for version 4).